# Using random.choice() to generate multiple times, then assign to a variable

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a game , and one of the functions needed is random text generation(*From a Dict*). For this I've been using the the **random.choice()** function with the random library. I want the code to generate a new result everytime the function is called. Here is the code:

```
colours = ["red","yellow","orange","green","blue","purple","grey"]
words = ["red","yellow","orange","green","blue","purple","grey"]
worrd = random.choice(words)
def get():
 print(ent.get())


def start():
 print("started")
 lab.pack_forget()
 sta.pack_forget()
 opt.pack(padx=5,pady=4)
 ent.pack(padx=5,pady=9)
 acc.pack(padx=7,pady=9)
 opt.config(text=worrd,fg=random.choice(colours))
```

How would I generate a new result from the **words** dict, and then assign it to the **worrd** variable?

Comment: So you mean that you want to move the line `worrd = random.choice(words)` into one of the functions?

Comment: You would call `random.choice(words)` *in* the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use random index:

```
import random
words = ["red","yellow","orange","green","blue","purple","grey"]
worrd=words[random.randint(0,len(words)-1)]
```

It's change worrd variable every time.